# In HCL OneTest UI, WebUI recording on Firefox browser is not working as it works in Chrome. #hclonetestui

Tags: ui-automation, webui

In HCL OneTest UI v10.0.2, when I launch Firefox browser for Web UI recording and try to record on the browser, it does not generate any test steps. I do not see any packets being collected in annotation toolbar.  I am using Firefox 68 ESR.I am able to record on Chrome but not on firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recording on browsers, HCL OneTest UI provides the Browser Extensions. When you launch Chrome browser for recording, it allows extension to be applied on the fly during browser launch while same is not true for firefox.
To resolve this, user is required to add HCL OneTest UI – Web UI Extension in the browser & launch the Firefox for Web UI recording in the same profile where extension is installed. You can follow these steps:

1. Install HCL OneTest UI – Web UI Extension on Firefox browser. The extension “webuirecorder_webext.xpi” can be seen at following directory in Windows OS:
   C:\Program Files\HCL\HCLIMShared\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.rtw.webgui.browextension.firefox_1.2.200.v20190529_2318\WebUIRecorderWebExtension

This location can vary a bit depending on your install location of HCL OneTest UI, please check for the similar location.

You can drag & drop the extension on Firefox browser and allow it to install on Firefox. Now you will see HCL OneTest UI – Web UI Extension has been added to Firefox.

[HCL OneTest UI - Web UI Extension for Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHuRX.png)

You can follow similar steps in Linux and Mac OS. 
e.g. In Linux it can be at: /opt/HCL/HCLIMShared/plugins/com.ibm.rational.test.rtw.webgui.browextension.firefox_/WebUIRecorderWebExtension

e.g. In MacOS it can be at: /Applications/HCL/HCLIMShared/plugins/com.ibm.rational.test.rtw.webgui.browextension.firefox_/WebUIRecorderWebExtension

2. When you start Web UI Recording on the Firefox browser, select the Firefox profile where the extension is installed, like shown below:

   [HCL OneTest UI - Recorder Wizard To Select Firefox browser in a profile for recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GByr1.png)

By default in Firefox ESR release, default-esr is the profile which is used by default by the firefox and most probably user might have applied the extension there. To verify which profile was the one where you have applied the extension, you can launch the firefox and open about:profiles url to view the profile name.

[Viewing Firefox Profile in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0ov3.png)

3. Now you should be able to proceed to record Web UI Test on Firefox browser.

Comment: Thanks in my case i had missed to see which profile recorder is using, that was the cause of the issue. It was using 'default' while extension was installed on default-release profile